# Regularity of semilinear parabolic PDE in the whole space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I need regularities in Holder space of the following parabolic PDE:
$$\partial_t v  = \partial_{xx} v + \partial_{yy} v + \rho \partial_{xy} v - v \partial_x v + \partial_y v + F, \forall (x, y, t) \in \mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^+,$$
with initial condition
$$v(x, y, 0) = \phi(x, y), \forall (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2.$$
In the above, $\rho\in [0,1]$ is a given constant and $F\in C^\infty_b(\mathbb R^3, \mathbb R)$ and $\phi\in C_b^2(\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R)$ are two given functions.

The above PDE is nonlinear only because the term $v \partial_x v$. I do not know where should I find the regularity theory of this type. Many available regularities from references are on bounded domain on $(x, y)$ but not the whole space. The whole space shall be much easier, but it's still too much if one should go for it from the scratch. Thanks.

Comment: If you ask for existence/uniqueness the nonlinearity is similar to that of the Navier-Stokes. Local existence holds and regularity in the whole space is as interior regularity: you can multiply v by a suitable cut-off function ϕ, write down the new equation for ϕv and apply the regularity results in a bounded domain. Hope I have understood well the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful and exactly what I wanted to ask. I have some clue for next search.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: perhaps convert your short comment to an answer?

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks. It is a short comment and I did not check the details; it is an equation I do not know well, so I prefer to keep it as a comment.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: Understood. FWIW, my first thought when I saw the question was also that "it looks a lot like Navier Stokes."

Comment: @WillieWong Indeed; it is also 2d and there could be some trick yielding global existence.

Comment: @OP: is $\rho$ supposed to be a constant?

Comment: @WillieWong yes, it is a constant between 0 and 1, I added it to the original writing.

Comment: then $\rho$ doesn't matter: you can get rid of it with a linear change of variables in $\mathbb{R}^2$; add to it a galilean change of variables, I am pretty sure you can rewrite your equation as exactly $$\partial_t v + v \partial_x v = \alpha \Delta v + F$$ Then you can apply what we know about Navier-Stokes (see Chapter 4 of https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781315373393/navier-stokes-problem-21st-century-pierre-gilles-lemari%C3%A9-rieusset for example) pretty much directly: you can skip the elliptic estimates for the pressure.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for your comments, it seems promising to me. I have to read the reference carefully.